# Remove strings contained in one QStringList, from another QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qstringlist

I was wondering if anyone knew of a Qt library method that can take two `QStringList` and remove all of the strings contained in one list from the second list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `QList::toSet()` method and do some `my_set1.substract(my_set2)`, and then go back `QSet::toList()`.
But this is just to play around with conversion code. You'd better code the logic yourself with the given lists, it will be faster and won't involve useless memory allocation (even if temporary)

Answer (score 8):

There is no library function in [`QList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) nor [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html).

But you can write your own method:

```
void remove(QStringList& list, const QStringList& toDelete){
  QStringListIterator i(toDelete);
  while(i.hasNext()){
    list.removeAll(i.next());
  }
}
```